# UIWebView select element options font

Tags: html, uitableview, fonts, uiwebview, uilabel

I have a webview and I'm using custom fonts (both in the webview and in the native controls).
But when I open an html dropdown the font rendered is the iOS default font.
To explain this better, the html element has something like this:

```
<select style="font-family:myfont">
    <option value="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">option 3</option>
    <option value="4">option 4</option>
</select>
```

when the drop element is clicked the webview opens a native UIPopoverController with a table containing the values. That table has the default font.

How can I change it??

I already tried using the appearance proxy, it is not supported.

```
[[UILabel appearance] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:kFont_Regular size:18.0]];
```

The problem here is that I don't have a tableview where I can implement the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method. Can I override that control?

Is there a way to set a default UITableViewCell that is used globally?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way as of yet to do this globally. I have to do it in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method as follows.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"My_FontName" size:17]];
    }

...
}
```